# Python.h: No such file or directory, when implementing python into c++, using CLion

Tags: python, c++, cygwin, clion

I have used "apt-cyg install python3-devel" on my Cygwin terminal.
I have included directories in CMake...

```
include_directories(C:/Users/{my_user_name}/anaconda3/include)
```

and importantly in my main.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
```

and have tried "Python.h", and "fullpath/Python.h".
I get back the error "fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory".
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several versions of `Python.h`, every one for its Cygwin python package

```
$ cygcheck -l python38-devel|grep Python.h
/usr/include/python3.8/Python.h

$ cygcheck -l python36-devel|grep Python.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
```

Anaconda is NOT a Cygwin python, so mixing will not work well.
`apt-cyg` is not the standard tool for installing Cygwin packages. Use Cygwin `setup` program to avoid problem.

Comment: using the new path it returns after running 'cygcheck -l python38-devel|grep Python.h', seems to work, thank you. You said Anaconda causes problems... Is there any way to avoid these problems? I would love to use the libraries included in Anaconda - or do I just have to install the libraries I want on this other instance of Python?